# imitating permutation function in mathematica using functional programming

Tags: functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica, permutation

I am creating all possible permutations of a set, say {1,2,3}, given that I can choose two numbers every time. I understand that this can be done using permutations function but my list can be very big and after creation of such a huge matrix it would take too long to do any operations on it. Hence, I wrote the following recursive function that does what I want:

```
h=Table[Null,{}]    
myset = {1, 2, 3};
numOfBins = 2;
h=Table[Null,{numOfBins}];
rec[x_] := (
   If[
    x <= numOfBins,
    Do[
     h[[x]] = j; 
     rec[x + 1],
     {j, 1, Length[myset]}
     ],
    Print[h]
    ]
   );
rec[1]
```

The outcome of the this code is:

```
{1,1}
{1,2}
{1,3}
{2,1}
{2,2}
{2,3}
{3,1}
{3,2} 
{3,3}
```

Now I would like to know how can I do this using functional programming maybe with Nest or NestWhile...

Comment: Wouldn't the matrix be same huge regardless of how you make it ?

Comment: I am not a pro but some how using the recursive function is faster.

Comment: The outome of the code looks more like Descartes' multiplication (set A multiplied by itself) rather than permutations. I think, you will get more specific help if you use this term in the title.

Answer (score 0):

If you request only those permutations of length 2, Mathematica can return the result rather quickly.

```
AbsoluteTiming[Permutations[Range[500], {2}]]
```

[image: permutations of length2]

Mathematica does not first generate all permutations  and then select those of length 2.  It cannot even handle the task of finding all permutations of a list of 500 items.

```
Permutations[Range[500]]
```

[image: all permutations]

Comment: well my problem is not limited to two, it may increase to 7 or 10 and this is a procedure that can repeat as well.

Comment: I see. Let me think a bit a bit about this.